# discord.py temprole command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

First of all i dont really know why its not working properly. Its not returning any errors, messages etc., the code is running properly. Can somebody help me fix my issue?

EDIT1: Just want to add that im noob in coding and ive spent about 1 hour trying to solve the problem

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$", intents=discord.Intents.default())

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

time_convert = {"sec":1, "min":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def temprole(ctx, role_time: int, member: discord.Member = None, role: discord.Role = None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who do you want me to give a role?")
        return
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send('Text me a role to add')
        return

    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Role has been given to {member.mention} \nfor {role_time}")

    await asyncio.sleep(role_time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{role.mention} has been removed from {member.mention} \n*(expired)*")

client.run('My Token Is Here')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have a [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIZoj.png) so you there are some missing intents
change this :

```
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$", intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

to

```
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$", intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Comment: its weird cuz i dont have this warning